Invariant Violation: new NativeEventEmitter() requires a non-null argument in Expo project using Firebase Auth
I'm building a React Native app with Expo and trying to integrate Firebase Authentication. I'm using @react-native-firebase/auth for email/password authentication, and I've configured Firebase for iOS. However, when I try to run the app, I get the following error:
Invariant Violation: new NativeEventEmitter() requires a non-null argument., js engine: hermes
Steps I've taken:
I added GoogleService-Info.plist to the root of the ios folder.
Updated app.json with the following:
{
  "expo": {
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.bertugmete.sorumvar",
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist"
    }
  }
}

My authentication code is as follows:
import { SafeAreaView, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleLogin = () => {
    auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('User account created & signed in!');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TextInput
        placeholder='Email'
        keyboardType='email-address'
        onChangeText={setEmail}
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder='Password'
        secureTextEntry={true}
        onChangeText={setPassword}
      />
      <Button title='Create User' onPress={handleLogin} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

Error:
Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument., js engine: hermes

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Is there an additional configuration I'm missing when using Firebase with Expo and Hermes?
